# Formula for Find Empty Space

Tags: c#

[View Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhJnC.png)

Hi everyone,

I need suggestions for a logic. My scenario is,

There is a empty space, `Size is Height: 200,  Width 200`

- I am filling some space `Height: 100, Width 100`
- Again I am filling space `Height : 50 Width : 50`

I just want to find empty space with direction. For Example

If I try to occupy `Height = 100 and Width = 200` it is Correct

If I try to occupy `Height = 200 and width = 100` It should say it is wrong.

See the image for clear idea

How to handle this scenario.. Any ideas?

---

Thank you all for your precious time, I think my question is not having enough details okay here am adding few more info with example,

I have a wood with size of (200 x 200) (H x W)

- First want to cut the wood with the size 100 x 100 
  (here I need the formula to check whether this value is available in this wood or not)
- now that formula should say, Yes it is available
- Again wants to cut with the size 50 x 50 
  (here I need the formula to check whether this value is available in this wood or not)
  -now formula should say, Yes it is available
- Again wants to cut with the size 100 x 200  (Height: 200, Width: 100)
  -Now formula should say, No this space is not available
- Again wants to cut with the size 200 x 100  (Height: 100, Width: 200)

  - Now formula should say, Yes it is available

Note: that cutting size may be changed 
I hope you understand what I am trying to say

Thanks

Comment: You're looking for a [2d bin packing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

Comment: Is the filled area constant or would it change?

Comment: That values may be change... I just said for example... it may be 20x30 or 110x50

Comment: Can the W:100 H:100 and W:50 and H:50 be changed. Of course the input values can be changed.

Comment: Is my answer good for you, or do you need more details?

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear about it.. Pls give some more details

Comment: Did you try to read the article in the link?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not enough well-defined to give you a complete answer. Anyway in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/210979/Fast-optimizing-rectangle-packing-algorithm-for-bu) post you can find a solution to the global problem of placing a series of rectangles into an anclosing rectangle.

The key of the solution is in the DynamicTwoDimensionArray class: every time you add a rectangle in your free space you cut your area in four parts, three of which are still empty. If you memorize the height and width of all your free spaces you just have to test if the new rectangle can fit in any of them.

Comment: You shouldn't need a 2D array as this method is only logical not physical, as far as the specs go we don't need to display the boxes.

Comment: I assume the OP just gave an example for his problem and, after he added the third box, he can ask if a fourth will fit.
The array of the free space (that I don't think is 2D) is needed to store the dimensions of all the already placed rectangles, not to draw them.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding of what OP is asking. We have to figure out what OP wants before we can help him. Unfortunately SumoS isn't being very clear.

Answer (score 1):

After the OP editied its question it is now clear what its program has to do.

The other answer I gave refers to a complete program that can be hard to follow and hard to use in one's design, so I decided to make everything from scratch.

Maybe it will be easier to follow and to use by any student that gets assigned the 2d bin packing problem.

Here we go...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WoodCutter {

    /// <summary>
    /// This class represents a continuous area of wood
    /// </summary>
    public class Freespace {
        private int x, y, height, width;
        /// <summary>
        /// Public constructor of the class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">Leftmost position of the area</param>
        /// <param name="y">Topmost position of the area</param>
        /// <param name="height">Vertical extent of the area</param>
        /// <param name="width">Horizontal extent of the area</param>
        public Freespace(int x, int y, int height, int width) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.height = height;
            this.width = width;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Leftmost position of the area
        /// </summary>
        public int xLeft {
            get { return this.x; }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Topmost position of the area
        /// </summary>
        public int yUp {
            get { return this.y; }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Tests if this area can contain a cut of the given height and width
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="height">Vertical extent of the needed cut</param>
        /// <param name="width">Horizontal extent of the needed cut</param>
        /// <returns>true if this Freespce can contain the needed cut else false</returns>
        public bool Contains(int height, int width) {
            if (this.width >= width && this.height >= height) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates cuts from this Freespace
        /// If the proposed cut does not intersect with this Freespace, do nothing and return a List containing this.
        /// If the proposed cut completely contains this Freespace, return an empty List.
        /// When the cut intersects the Freespace, cut the Freespace with the semiplanes around the desired cut
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">Leftmost position of the cut</param>
        /// <param name="y">Topmost position of the cut</param>
        /// <param name="height">Vertical extent of the cut</param>
        /// <param name="width">Horizontal extent of the cut</param>
        /// <returns>List of Freespaces created from the intersection of the Freespace and the cut</returns>
        public List<Freespace> Cut(int x, int y, int height, int width) {
            List<Freespace> res = new List<Freespace>();
            if ((x - this.x) >= this.width || 
                (y - this.y) >= this.height || 
                (x + width) < this.x || 
                (y + height) < this.y) {
                // no intersection, return myself
                res.Add(this);
                return res;
            }
            if (x <= this.x && 
                y <= this.y && 
                (x + width) >= (this.x + this.width) && 
                (y + height) >= (this.y + this.height)) {
                // the cut covers the whole freespce, return empty list
                return res;
            }
            if (x > this.x) {
                // cut this freespace with the semiplane of abscissas less than x
                res.Add(new Freespace(this.x, this.y, this.height, x - this.x));
            }
            if (y > this.y) {
                // cut this freespace with the semiplane of ordinates less than y
                res.Add(new Freespace(this.x, this.y, y - this.y, this.width));
            }
            if ((x + width) < (this.x + this.width)) {
                // cut this freespace with the semiplane of abscissas greater than x+width
                res.Add(new Freespace(x + width, this.y, this.height, this.width - width));
            }
            if ((y + height) < (this.y + this.height)) {   
                // cut this freespace with the semiplane of ordinates greater than y+height
                res.Add(new Freespace(x, y + height, this.height - height, this.width));
            }
            return res;
        }
        public void Write2Console() {
            Console.WriteLine("Freespace at {0},{1} of dimensions {2},{3}", this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This class holds a List of Freespaces that can be cut
    /// At the beginning you have only one Freespace covering the whole plane, 
    /// adding cuts the List gets populated with all the residual areas.
    /// </summary>
    public class Wood {
        private List<Freespace> freeSpaces;
        /// <summary>
        /// Public constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="height">Vertical extent of the area</param>
        /// <param name="width">Horizontal extent of the area</param>
        public Wood(int height, int width) {
            this.freeSpaces = new List<Freespace>();
            this.freeSpaces.Add(new Freespace(0, 0, height, width));
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the first Freespace (or null) that can contain the whole cut
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="height">Vertical extent of the cut</param>
        /// <param name="width">Horizontal extent of the cut</param>
        /// <returns>First Freespace completely containing the cut or null</returns>
        public Freespace canCut(int height, int width) {
            foreach (Freespace f in this.freeSpaces) {
                if (f.Contains(height, width)) {
                    return f;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Makes the cut in the Wood.
        /// Intersects the desired cut with all the Freespaces in the List.
        /// WARNING. No check is made, at this point, if you can do the cut. 
        ///          You have to call the canCut function before using this method 
        ///          and take the adequate coordinates from the Freespace returned.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">Leftmost position of the cut</param>
        /// <param name="y">Topmost position of the cut</param>
        /// <param name="height">Vertical extent of the cut</param>
        /// <param name="width">Horizontal extent of the cut</param>
        public void Cut(int x, int y, int height, int width) {
            List<Freespace> freeSpaces = new List<Freespace>();
            foreach (Freespace f in this.freeSpaces) {
                freeSpaces.AddRange(f.Cut(x, y, height, width));
            }
            this.freeSpaces = freeSpaces;
        }
        public void Write2Console() {
            foreach (Freespace f in this.freeSpaces) {
                f.Write2Console();
            }
        }
    }

    class WoodCutter {
        /// <summary>
        /// Tests if a cut can be made in the wood and, if true
        /// cuts it at the upper leftmost coordinate of the first
        /// adequate Freespace found.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="wood">The wood to cut</param>
        /// <param name="width">The width of thr cut</param>
        /// <param name="heigth">The height of the cut</param>
        private static void testCut(Wood wood, int width, int heigth) {
            Freespace f;
            f = wood.canCut(heigth, width);
            if (f != null) {
                Console.WriteLine("Can cut a {0} by {1} piece", width, heigth);
                wood.Cut(f.xLeft, f.yUp, heigth, width);
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot fit a {0} by {1} piece", width, heigth);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // Let's start with a 200X200 wood
            Wood wood = new Wood(200, 200);
            wood.Write2Console();

            //Try and cut a 100X100 piece
            testCut(wood, 100, 100);
            wood.Write2Console();

            //Try and cut a 50X50 piece
            testCut(wood, 50, 50);
            wood.Write2Console();

            //Try to cut a 100X200 piece (this should fail)
            testCut(wood, 100, 200);
            wood.Write2Console();

            //Try and cut a 200X100 piece
            testCut(wood, 200, 100);
            wood.Write2Console();

            Console.WriteLine("Program end.");
        }
    }
}
```

The best you can do is run the code and step through it to understand how it works. The following is the expected output:

```
Freespace at 0,0 of dimensions 200,200
Can cut a 100 by 100 piece
Freespace at 100,0 of dimensions 100,200
Freespace at 0,100 of dimensions 200,100
Can cut a 50 by 50 piece
Freespace at 150,0 of dimensions 50,200
Freespace at 100,50 of dimensions 100,150
Freespace at 0,100 of dimensions 200,100
Cannot fit a 100 by 200 piece
Freespace at 150,0 of dimensions 50,200
Freespace at 100,50 of dimensions 100,150
Freespace at 0,100 of dimensions 200,100
Can cut a 200 by 100 piece
Freespace at 150,0 of dimensions 50,100
Freespace at 100,50 of dimensions 100,50
```

Hope it helps, for any questions upvote and comment :D.

Comment: This is a good solution. how ever i did this with bitarray but it was a lot slower. but your solution is fast.

Comment: The problem with bitarrays is that you loose the *shape* of the area left, so you need to verify each time how many pixels are free in each direction. The classes I implemented always enable you to ask for the maximum dimension you have left.

Comment: I fixed that problem. what i did was to create another space called `FillerObject` and it would start to fit inside bitarray. so for 200*200 bitarray it had to start from index 0 and try to fill inside bitarray and also keeping its shape. if it failed then start putting that object from index 1 and so on. it worked correctly as yours but real slow. nice solution btw :-)

Comment: Sorry, I was misunderstood. You can solve the problem with bitarrays but, as you did, you must verify each time that you have enough bits left (in both directions) to accomodate your required cut. This makes the process iterative and, then slow. That's why you need a better designed structure that make easier to know if the area you are cutting can fit the freespace. 

Imagine you want to solve the 3D problem, the complexity of the bitarray approach will become O(n^3), the `Freespace` approach would still be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

This solution works assuming the area that is filled is constant.

```
private static bool NewValueFit(int xfoo, int ybar)
{
    if (xfoo > 200 || ybar > 200)
        return false;            
    if (ybar <= 100)
        return true;
    else if (ybar <= 150)
    {
        if (xfoo <= 100)
            return true;
    else
            return false;
    }
    else if (xfoo <= 50)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```